# Why is a list of dictionaries empty when the dictionary contents are appended to list and the dictionary is cleared in every iteration?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to populate a dictionary and append it to a list. This has to be done in a loop. At the end of each iteration i wish to clear the dictionary. Finally, i want to return this list.

Here is what i have tried -

```py
data_list = []
data_dict = {}
region_dict = {'1234':'198.18.111.222', '4567':'198.18.333.444'}
for region, ip in region_dict.items():
   data_dict['region'] = region
   data_dict['IP'] = ip
   data_list.append(data_dict)
   data_dict.clear()
return data_list
```

I expect the output to be returned as -

```py
   [{'region':'1234', 'IP':'198.18.111.222'}, {'region':'4567', 'IP':'198.18.333.444'}]
```

But what is actually returned is

```py
   [{}]
```

Comment: you are appending the same dictionary (in memory) and then clearing the dictionary. I get `[{}, {}]` btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using list comprehension

```
[{'region': region, 'IP': ip} for region, ip in region_dict.items()]
# Output
# [{'region': '4567', 'IP': '198.18.333.444'}, {'region': '1234', 'IP': '198.18.111.222'}]
```

What you've done in your code is somewhat similar to the below. Notice how changes to `a` affect the list. That's because the list holds pointers to the dictionary `a` in memory

```
>>> a = {'key': 'value'}
>>> myList = [a, a]
>>> a['key'] = 6
>>> myList
[{'key': 6}, {'key': 6}]
```

**EDIT**

To answer your comment, you can do this:

```
data_list = []
data_dict = {}
region_dict = {'1234':'198.18.111.222', '4567':'198.18.333.444'}
for region, ip in region_dict.items():
   data_dict['region'] = region
   data_dict['IP'] = ip
   data_list.append(data_dict)
   data_dict = {}               <----

print(data_list)
```

But it's cleaner to do this:

```
data_list = []
region_dict = {'1234':'198.18.111.222', '4567':'198.18.333.444'}
for region, ip in region_dict.items():
   data_dict = {}
   data_dict['region'] = region
   data_dict['IP'] = ip
   data_list.append(data_dict)

print(data_list)
```

Or better yet:

```
data_list = []
region_dict = {'1234':'198.18.111.222', '4567':'198.18.333.444'}
for region, ip in region_dict.items():
   data_dict = {'region': region, 'IP': ip}
   data_list.append(data_dict)

print(data_list)
```

Which is exactly equivalent to

`[{'region': region, 'IP': ip} for region, ip in region_dict.items()]`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. So in that case, how do we keep the list and dict as separate entities, instead of having pointers? If i want to do some stuff inside the for loop and add more data to data_dict based on the 'region' and 'ip' values, how do we append this data_dict to list and also clear it in each iteration.